# Service class is not injected in Angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular-directive

I already had everything working yesterday. And today, after I restarted the environment, one of the services that I am trying to inject, is now always `null`.

Here is my top level component (app.component.ts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'priz-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SecureRouterOutlet],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, AuthenticationService]
})
```

The template of that component contains:
`<secure-outlet signin="Login" unauthorized="AccessDenied"></secure-outlet>`

Where the `secure-outlet` implementation is as follows:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'secure-outlet'
})
export class SecureRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    @Input()
    signin: string;

    @Input()
    unauthorized:string;

    @Input()
    nameAttr: string;

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
                private parentRouter: Router,
                private authService: AuthenticationService,
                public injector: Injector) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, parentRouter, null);
    }
...
```

In the constructor, as well as anywhere else in the directive, `authService` is always `null`. I tried, defining providers with `AuthenticationService` inside the directive, in the main component, even in the bootstrap, nothing works.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: first remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from providers array and use it in bootstrap function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` to components, **only** to `bootstrap()`

Try providing the same parameters as the original `RouterOutlet` class and add your own dependencies behind them. 
Not sure if this helps though but I think it was mentioned not too long ago that there is a weird issue:

```
constructor(
    _elementRef: ElementRef, 
    _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
    private parentRouter: Router,
    @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string, // <= added
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    public injector: Injector) {
```

Comment: Ok, that actually works, and even kind of make sense. However, now I am getting this error: `/Users/ShurikAg/Dev/angular2/ng2/src/shared/directives/securerouter.directive.ts
      line 47  col 17  In the constructor of class "SecureRouterOutlet", the parameter "nameAttr" uses the @Attribute decorator, which is considered as a bad practice. Please, consider construction of type "@Input() nameAttr: string"`.

Comment: Hmm, to me it doesn't make sense. IMHO the number, kind and order of dependencies in the constructor shouldn't matter. Seems like there is something fishy going on how the router outlet is instantiated. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7569 is the discussion where I saw this mentioned.

Comment: What should I do with the error? I mean, it still works, but there is a reason why @Attribute decorator is a bad practice.

Comment: Ah, didn't read the full comment. That's a very weird message. No idea what produces it. I also don't see what's bad about it. If you are only interested in static values and don't want to be notified about later updates `@Attribute` is just fine. `@Input()` would be quite cumbersome this the actual use case. I can't find this error message in the Angular2 GitHub repo.